# Perform Asynchronous Decorations in DraftJS?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, draftjs

I'm trying to perform real-time Named Entity Recognition highlighting in a WYSIWYG editor, which requires me to make a request to my back-end in between each keystroke.

After spending about a week on ProseMirror I gave up on it and decided to try DraftJS. I have searched the repository and docs and haven't found any asynchronous examples using `Decorations`. (There are some examples with `Entities`, but they seem like a bad fit for my problem.)

Here is the [stripped down Codepen](https://codepen.io/Nolence/pen/NoLQzK?editors=0010) of what I'd like to solve.

It boils down to me wanting to do something like this:

```
const handleStrategy = (contentBlock, callback, contentState) => {
  const text = contentBlock.getText();
  let matchArr, start;
  while ((matchArr = properNouns.exec(text)) !== null) {
    start = matchArr.index;
    setTimeout(() => {
//    THROWS ERROR: Cannot read property '0' of null
      callback(start, start + matchArr[0].length);
    }, 200) // to simulate API request
  }
};
```

I expected it to asynchronously call the callback once the timeout resolved but instead `matchArr` is empty, which just confuses me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why you need to perform async inside the Decorator's strategy function? I don't get it. I believe you don't fully understand whats the Decorator's strategy function is doing. And what data will you get from backend with every keystroke?

Comment: I mean I don't get the logic of your question, the only async operation is getting data from backend, there no need of async operation within the draftjs editor

Comment: Hi platt, you're perfectly right that I don't completely understand what the decorator's strategy is doing (I've only studied the library for a day or two), but what I want isn't such an odd case I think. I essentially want to send what the user has typed so far to a server with a NLP processing toolkit, where each word will be marked with an entity type. It'll then send the result back to the front in json like`{"I": "Subj", "want": "Verb", ...}`. With that information, I'll highlight each word based off what part of speech it is. I want to do this in real time though and not in one big batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, one possible solution, a example, simple version (may not be 100% solid) :

1. write a function take editor's string, send it to server, and resolve the data get from server, you need to figure out send the whole editor string or just one word

```
getServerResult = data => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ...

      fetch(link, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          ...
        },
        // figure what to send here
        body: this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText(),
      })
        .then(res => resolve(res))
        .catch(reject);
    });
```

2. determine when to call the getServerResult function(i.e when to send string to server and get entity data), from what I understand from your comment, when user hit spacebar key, send the word before to server, this can done by draftjs [Key Bindings](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-key-bindings) or react [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events). You will need to handle case what if user hit spacebar many times continuously.

```
function myKeyBindingFn(e: SyntheticKeyboardEvent): string {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    return 'send-server';
  }
  return getDefaultKeyBinding(e);
}

async handleKeyCommand(command: string): DraftHandleValue {
  if (command === 'send-server') {
    // you need to manually add a space char to the editorState
    // and get result from server

    ...

    // entity data get from server
    const result = await getServerResult()

    return 'handled';
  }
  return 'not-handled';
}
```

3. add entity data get from server to specific word using ContentState.[createEntity()](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state#createentity)

```
  async handleKeyCommand(command: string): DraftHandleValue {
    if (command === 'send-server') {
      // you need to manually add a space char to the editorState
      // and get result from server

      ...

      // entity data get from server
      const result = await getServerResult()

      const newContentState = ContentState.createEntity(
        type: 'string',
        mutability: ...
        data: result
      )

      const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();

      // you need to figure out the selectionState, selectionState mean add 
      // the entity data to where

      const contentStateWithEntity = Modifier.applyEntity(
         newContentState,
         selectionState,
         entityKey
      );

      // create a new EditorState and use this.setState()
      const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
        ...
        contentState: contentStateWithEntity
      )

      this.setState({
        editorState: newEditorState
      })

      return 'handled';
    }
    return 'not-handled';
  }
```

4. create different decorators find words with specific entity data, and return different style or whatever you need to return

```
...
const compositeDecorator = new CompositeDecorator([
  strategy: findSubjStrategy,
  component: HandleSubjSpan,
])
```

```
function findSubjStrategy(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
  // search whole editor content find words with subj entity data
  // if the word's entity data === 'Subj'
  // pass the start index & end index of the word to callback

  ...
  if(...) {
   ... 
   callback(startIndex, endIndex);
  }
}

// this function handle what if findSubjStrategy() find any word with subj
// entity data
const HandleSubjSpan = (props) => {

  // if the word with subj entity data, it font color become red
  return <span {...props} style={{ color: 'red' }}>{props.children}</span>;
};
```

Comment: THanks Plat! I got it most of the way there thanks to you. I decided to make a few changes here and there but you can see for yourself [here](https://codepen.io/Nolence/pen/LqgXGw?editors=0011).